# Alternatives of getline

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class publication {
private:
  string title;
  float price;

public:
  publication() {
    this->title = "";
    this->price = 0.0;
  }

  void getdata() {
    cout << "Enter Title: ";
    getline(cin, title);
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    cin >> this->price;
  }

  void putdata() {
    cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
    cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
  }
};

class book : public publication {
private:
  int pageCount;

public:
  book() { this->pageCount = 0; }

  void getdata() {
    publication::getdata();
    cout << "Enter page count: ";
    cin >> pageCount;
  }

  void putdata() {
    publication::putdata();
    cout << "Page Count: " << pageCount << " pages\n";
  }
};

class tape : public publication {
private:
  float playingTime;

public:
  tape() { this->playingTime = 0; }

  void getdata() {
    publication::getdata();
    cout << "Enter playing time: ";
    cin >> playingTime;
  }

  void putdata() {
    publication::putdata();
    cout << "Playing Time: " << playingTime << " mins\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  book b;
  tape t;
  b.getdata();
  t.getdata();
  b.putdata();
  t.putdata();
  return 0;
}
```

The first time `getline()` works perfectly, but the second time it's called, it gets skipped because of some `cin >> value;` has executed before it.
I tried adding a `cin.ignore()` before `getline()`, but it either requires me to press enter before giving an input, or skips the first character of the first input.

However, if I add `cin.ignore()` after the end of every `cin >> value;` block, it works.

So so I have to suddenly add `cin.ignore()` everywhere because of one `getline()`?
Or is there any alternative for `getline()` to take spaces as input?

Comment: You might use `getline` everywhere, and parse the line afterward.

Comment: C++ stream input is not entirely crazy of a design, but it’s certainly far from being intuitive when you first try it. There have been literally dozens of similar questions on SO in the last few weeks - probably related to a new school term starting somewhere in the world. You’d do well to read those other questions and their answers. It’s all been re-hashed a million times by now. Questions like yours are always duplicates because of how common a problem it is. Your real problem is with learning how to search on SO - that does take some experience and is.m not trivial. Treat it seriously.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of a dozen other questions almost exactly like it.

Comment: BTW, you should be more consistent in your coding:  always use `this->` or not.  You don't need to use `this->` syntax unless you are differentiating member variables from parameters (less typing == less injected defects).

Comment: I guess the title was misleading for this question to be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the behaviour is fully according to the specification. `std::getline` works as expected.

You need to read about formatted input and unformatted input to understand why it is implemented as it is.

However, you are looking for solutions.
There are basically 3:

- Use `ignore` after your formatted input. Unfortunately after every formatted input
- append one `get` to your input statement, like `(cin >> pageCount).get();`. Again, unfortunately after every formatted input
- Use the `std::ws` manipulator in the `std::getline`. Like: `getline(cin >> ws, title);`. This will eat *potential* leading whitespaces, including the newline.

Please see the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws).

It has the additional advantage that, if the user enters unnecessary whitespace in front of the title, those will be ignored. Example: Input: `"   This is the title"` will read `"This is the title"`, without leading white spaces.

So, what could do is: Use

```
getline(cin >> ws, title);
```

and it will work.

Please `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: Re: "Unfortunately after every formatted input" -- no. Only on the **transition** from formatted input to unformatted input.

Comment: I like that trick with `std::ws`; haven't seen it before. +1.